# Update PATH variable during script execution

Tags: environment-variables

I am writing a script that installs a program.  The problem is the program needs to have PATH variables set to install.

How do I set PATH variables during the script execution and update the shell so the installation can finish with one sweep?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:[path to add]

[ shell program here          ]
[ e.g. sudo dpkg -i xyz.deb   ]
```

This will add PATH variables to the system which will reset on closing of the terminal. To permanently change them, add the PATH=... line to `.bashrc`